# how can i get child state value to parent using useRef in reactjs + typescript (hooks)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am new to Typescript.  I need to get the child state values to the parent using ref on a button click to update the reducer values.

I have tried passing a `ref` to the child but I am getting errors similar to this:

> Type '{ value: string; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | undefined>; }'
> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
>
> Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

parent component

```
import React, from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {
    Page,
    Welcome,
    ErrorBoundary
} from "components";
const ParentDiv = styled.div`
            margin: 0 410px 30px 15px;
            `;

export const CreateEvent = (props: any) => {

    return (
        <Page title='Dashboard'>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                {(() => {
                    switch (activeEventStage?.step) {
                        case 1:
                            return (
                                <ErrorBoundary>
                                    <Welcome />
                                </ErrorBoundary>
                            );
                        default:
                            return null;
                    }
                })()}
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </Page>
    );
};
export default withRouter(CreateEvent);
```

child component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

export const Welcome = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        welBannerTagline: "",
        welHeroTitle: "",
    });

    return (
        <CreateEventFormContainer
            title={t("event.create.title")}
            subTitile={t("welcome.subTitle")}
        >
            <>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <DropZoneInputField
                            titleName={t("welcome.bgImage.title")}
                            onSelectedFiles={onDropFiles}
                            imageType='bgImage'
                            value={state.welBgFilename}
                        />
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg='6'>
                        <DropZoneInputField
                            titleName={t("welcome.banner.title")}
                            onSelectedFiles={onDropFiles}
                            imageType='bannerImage'
                            value={state.welBannerFilname}
                        />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </>
        </CreateEventFormContainer>
    );
};
export default Welcome;
```

Comment: where are u using useRef? I dont see it in the code above

Comment: i have removed that because its breaking my work, i only need the solution using typescript in hooks to get the child state values

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `Welcome` is not designed to accept a `ref` prop.

`ref` is a reserved prop name in React so in order to pass a prop `ref` to a child component, that child must use [`React.forwardRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) to accept the `ref` prop.

You can pass the ref object directly with any other prop name, for example `myRef`.  In that case you don't need to use `forwardRef` but you **do** need to make sure that the props of the child accept a prop `myRef` which is a ref.

The type for the ref itself depends on where it will be eventually attached to the DOM.  Probably an `HTMLButtonElement`?

```
interface WelcomeProps {
    myRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLButtonElement | null>;
}

export const Welcome = ({myRef}: WelcomeProps) => {
...
```

```
export const CreateEvent = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
    const refObject = React.useRef<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);
    return (
...
       <Welcome myRef={refObject}/>
...
```

This allows you to interact with the DOM.  But that doesn't seem like what you actually want to do.

> I need to get the child state values to the parent using ref on a button click to update the reducer values.

Just pass a callback!  Should the state even be stored in the child, or can you [lift it up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up) to the parent?

```
interface CallbackValue {
    // what properties does the callback want to receive?
    welBannerTagline: string;
    welHeroTitle: string;
}

interface WelcomeProps {
    myCallback: (value: CallbackValue) => void;
}

export const Welcome = ({myCallback}: WelcomeProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        welBannerTagline: "",
        welHeroTitle: "",
    });

    const handleEvent = () => {
        myCallback(state);
    }
...
```

```
export const CreateEvent = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
    return (
...
       <Welcome myCallback={(value) => {
           // do something here with the value
       }} />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way is to use the `useRef` hook built into React with the reserved `ref` prop.  It only works on mutable objects so you don't have to worry about typing it yourself.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export const CreateEvent = (props: any) => {

    const welcomeRef = useRef();

    return (
        <Page title='Dashboard'>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                {(() => {
                    switch (activeEventStage?.step) {
                        case 1:
                            return (
                                <ErrorBoundary>
                                    <Welcome ref={welcomeRef} />
                                </ErrorBoundary>
                            );
                        default:
                            return null;
                    }
                })()}
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </Page>
    );
};
export default withRouter(CreateEvent);
```